# how to generate error if date in not in given format php

Tags: php

I want to generate an error if received date is not in the below format in PHP.

```
m/d/yyyy
m-d-yyyy
yyyy/mm/dd
yyyy-mm-dd
yyyy-m-d
yyyy/m/d
mm-dd-yyyy
mm/dd/yyyy

mm/dd/yy
m/d/yy
mm-dd-yy
m-d-yy


function validateDate($date, $format = 'Y-m-d')
{
$d = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $date);
return $d && $d->format($format) == $date;
}
```

I am trying with function

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please have a look at How to ask good questions on SO. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Just a minor thing - what if the format is dd/mm/yyyy (etc.)

Comment: Can you try (bool)strtotime($yourDateString)

Comment: @NigelRen then there must throw an error

Comment: This can lead to all sorts of ambiguous dates including 13-01-12.

Comment: @NigelRen I understand, My question is , is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try my below code

```
<?php

$yourDateString = "05-25-2012";
$testDate       = str_replace("-","/",$yourDateString);
$stat           =  (bool)strtotime($testDate) ;

if($stat && (preg_match('/^[0-9 \- \/]+$/',$yourDateString)))
    echo "Valid Date";
else
    echo "Not Valid Date";
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the OP's question. The OP only wants to allow some specific formats and throw errors if any other format is passed in (even if PHP might accept it.) This would return true for _all_ formats that PHP can understand.

Comment: Okay I ll alter my answer now @amaan

Comment: @Ajith Thanks, but it's not working on all format 05-25-2012, this is being failed

Comment: @amandeep Can you check now?